# Ошибка в простейшем веб-скрейпинге

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Я захотел написать парсер, который бы стянул информацию с сайта и сохранил в документ. Решил воспользоваться данной статьей хабра:
https://habr.com/ru/post/280238/

В ней представлен следующий код:

```
import requests
user_id = 12345
url = 'http://www.kinopoisk.ru/user/%d/votes/list/ord/date/page/2/#list' % (user_id) # url для второй страницы
r = requests.get(url)
with open('test.html', 'w') as output_file:
  output_file.write(r.text.encode('cp1251'))
```

Скопировал первые строки кода, однако они выдали ошибку, при использовании с тем сайтом, что я хочу запарсить. Ссылка на сайт(если это важно) вот: [https://ru.investing.com/stock-screener/?sp=country::5|sector::a|industry::a|equityType::a|exchange::2%3Ceq_market_cap;1](https://ru.investing.com/stock-screener/?sp=country::5%7Csector::a%7Cindustry::a%7CequityType::a%7Cexchange::2%3Ceq_market_cap;1)

Соответственно, проблемы следующие:

1. Если просто втупую скопировать код с хабра, подставив свой URL, то выдает следующую ошибку: "ValueError: unsupported format character 'C' (0x43) at index 104" в строке url = " " % (user_id). Что эта ошибка означает, я не понимаю.
2. Так как в данном случае я не понимаю, что делает строка номер три в примере с хабра,(для меня это присвоение переменной url остатка от деления адреса страницы на userid, был бы признателен тому, что подскажет реальный смысл этой строки), то я решил переделать код в следующий:

   ```
   import requests
   url = 'https://ru.investing.com/stock-screener/? 
   sp=country::5|sector::a|industry::a|equityType::a|exchange::2%3Ceq_market_cap;1' 
   r = requests.get(url)
   with open('test.html', 'w') as output_file:
      output_file.write(r.text.encode('cp1251'))
   ```

И данный код выдает ошибку "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes"

В итоге прошу помочь мне разобраться с этим цирком. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Приведите код с хабра в текстовом виде, а не по ссылке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это регулярно встречающаяся тут в вопросах ошибка. Не все символы `UTF-8` можно записать в кодировке `cp1251`. Пишите файл как есть в `UTF-8`, вы можете потом спокойно его прочитать даже в `Windows` без каких-либо проблем.

```
output_file.write(r.text)
```

P.S. Похоже, текст там уже в кодировке `cp1251`, его не надо ещё раз перекодировать в неё.

Comment: Отлично, большое спасибо, все заработало, вывело что я забанен на этом сайте потому что робот. То, на что я и расчитывал.

Comment: Единственный оставшийся вопрос - можете ли пояснить, что все-таки делает строка url = 'http://www.kinopoisk.ru/user/%d/votes/list/ord/date/page/2/#list' % (user_id)?

Comment: @OlehChaika Это подстановка значения переменной `user_id` в строку-шаблон (на то место, где в строке `%d`, если я правильно помню).